# Where to submit collected malware from my honeypot?

Tags: malware, honeypot

wondering if you could help me. i setup the Dionaea honeypot and have collected 6 or 7 malware files. Unfortunately upon checking the Dionaea logs it keeps giving the error "Couldn't resolve host" for Norman sandbox, Anubis and CW Sandbox. I tried finding the named sites myself but got nowhere, the results googled return linked to some sort of corporate sandboxes (has cw sandbox been sold off?).

I did try virus total but when uploading the file it just hangs saying "computing hash" and nothing happens. Files are stored as plain text files. They are still sitting on my honeypot (which is Ubuntu) dont dare move them to my windows machine!

Anyone know what happened to CW Sandbox? Is there another analyser I can use?

Thanks for your help

P.S I looked in this thread: [Honeypot on home network to help me learn](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/honeypot-on-home-network-to-help-me-learn) but question asked is not the same as mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://cwsandbox.org/ explains it all. The product is now called Threat Track.

They have an [uploader form](http://www.threattracksecurity.com/resources/sandbox-malware-analysis.aspx).

Comment: as a bonus, I will link to the Anubis "how do I auto-submit" FAQ: https://anubis.iseclab.org/?action=faq