# How to configure routing infrastructure so that the appropriate network traffic gets passed to the honeypot machine (windows xp)

Tags: windows, configuration, honeypot

I would like to configure local honeypot on windows xp which is installed on vmware, to do so I follow instruction on this [link](http://windowsitpro.com/security/honeyd-configuration-steps), but as I am new I don't know how can I configure routing infrastructure so that the appropriate network traffic gets passed to the honeypot machine.
could any one help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a honeypot. Who do you want to catch?

If you want to catch random people scanning your network, put it on your [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) with a publicly accessible host name. Something juicy like, financial01.yoursite.com.

If you want to catch someone who has already penetrated your network and is poking around, put it behind a router with a bunch of other machines. Again, choose an identity for it that will catch attention -- 100 open ports, maybe?

A honeypot is your way to solicit the attention of bad people. Put it where they will look. Then wait.

Also, read the answers for this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/honeypot-on-home-network-to-help-me-learn?rq=1). It discusses a lot of the things you're looking for, and elaborates on how you can protect the rest of your network from all the attention your honeypot will get.